# Execute a code when button is pressed and drag and drop box - Kivy, Python

Tags: python, button, kivy, kivy-language

I'm new to Kivy and this is the window I've created using Kivy. I've got a code that executes each of the yellow buttons below but I'm not sure on how to link the button to the python code. Also I'm stuck on creating a drag and drop box. Currently, in the image, the drag and drop box is a button.

My main aim is to get the intensity from the textbox and the image to do each of the functions below. Ay help would be grateful! Thank you

[image]

Kivy code

```
import kivy

kivy.require("1.9.0")

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.clearcolor = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1)


class CalcGridLayout(GridLayout):

    # Function called when equals is pressed
    def calculate(self, calculation):
        if calculation:
            try:
                # Solve formula and display it in entry
                # which is pointed at by display
                self.display.text = str(eval(calculation))
            except Exception:
                self.display.text = "Error"


class CalculatorApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return CalcGridLayout()


calcApp = CalculatorApp()
calcApp.run()
```

kv file code

```
# Custom button
<CustButton@Button>:
    font_size: 32
    background_normal: 'Colour_yellow.png'
    background_down: 'Colour_blue.png'

<Cust2@Button>:
    font_size: 32
    background_normal: 'Colour_red.png'
    background_down: 'Colour_blue.png'

<Cust3@Button>:
    font_size: 32
    background_normal: 'Colour_white.png'
    background_down: 'Colour_blue.png'

<Cust4@Button>:
    font_size: 32
    background_normal: 'Colour_blue.png'
    background_down: 'Colour_white.png'

# Define id so I can refer to the CalcGridLayout
# class functions
# Display points to the entry widget
<CalcGridLayout>:
    id: calculator
    display: entry
    rows: 5
    padding: 10
    spacing: 10


    BoxLayout:
        spacing: 100
        size_hint: .5, None
        Cust2:
            text: "Whats the intensity you want?"

    # Where input is displayed
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: .5, None
        TextInput:
            id: entry
            font_size: 70
            multiline: False
            hint_text: "Type here"

    BoxLayout:
        spacing: 100
        size_hint: .5, None
        Cust4:
            text: "Drag and Drop picture below:"

    BoxLayout:
        Cust3:
            text: "Drag and Drop picture"
            color: 0, 0, 0, 1


    # When equals is pressed pass text in the entry
    # to the calculate function
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: 1, .3
        spacing: 10
        CustButton:
            text: "Click here for \n reduced size"

        CustButton:
            text: "Click here for pos \n  and intensity of \n      each pixel"

        CustButton:
            text: "Click here \n for graph"

        CustButton:
            text: "Click here \n     for all"

        CustButton:
            text: "Extra"
```

Answer (score 0):

## Button Binding

1. In Python script, implement the methods for each button into class `CalcGridLayout(GridLayout):` e.g. `def method_name(self, instance):`
2. In kv file, add `on_release: root.method_name()` or `on_press: root.method_name()` under each `CustButton:` to bind to different methods.